# How to close native Blackberry applications programmatically from third party app? 

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to develop an app which can "Block the Invocation of some Blackberry native app's" whenever that applications get opened.

My problem is, how can any native application get closed through a background thread of other third party application? I have tried to pass "Escape" key event but it's not passing to the native app through a third party app's thread.

Is there any way to get the menu of the native application (from the background thread of other application) to execute the “close” command of that native application?

I have tried free version of Mr. Safe, from the Blackberry application world. It blocks selected applications successfully. You can see it here: http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/63110/?lang=en

So I am sure there must be a way to close native apps from another third party app, but don't know how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Block Blackberry Application programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946964/how-to-block-blackberry-application-programmatically)

Comment: Hey can you please check my blog: http://blogformobile.wordpress.com/

Comment: Thanks for ur replay. This link block is useful to block application on programeticaly. if i need to block some particular app. like i need to block only camera or wifi than how it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem -
My solution is given on supportforums.blackberry.com - [solution](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/global-event-listener-is-not-called-instantly-and-properly-on/m-p/1741225#M200533).

Or you can go directly to main thread - [main thread starts form here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/global-event-listener-is-not-called-instantly-and-properly-on/m-p/1730073).