# How to Block Blackberry Application programmatically?

Tags: blackberry

How to Block BlackBerry native application or Third party application.

e.g. - Enable and Disable camera.
     - Enable and Disable Wifi  connection.
     - Block Facebook,twitter app.

Same as Mr.safe application on BlackBerry app world.

[http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/63110/?lang=en][1]

How it Possible to programatically ?

Answer (score 1):

They just listen for app foregrounding and invoke their app foreground at this moment.

Here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968142/blackberry-background-application-to-listen-starts-and-foreground-app) how to listen app foreground event.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, But my question is how to Disable native application and Block third party app. not only know that which app is running or install. e.g. i need to lock camera than blackberry user can't able to use camera on device.

Comment: Did you try this app? They don't disable app. When you try to start "locked" app it actually starts but immediately lock app is foregrounding it and asking password.

Comment: Thanks,This forum is very useful. In this application i get my current open application. Now how can i close this open application by this application?

Comment: They don't close app. They just call foreground their app which hides open app. You could see that this app is still run in background. But when you'll try to maximize it again everything repeats.